# java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-image

I'm trying to load images from url in a listview in android. I'm using below piece of code to do that.

```
        Bitmap bm;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I'm executing the above code in an AsyncTask. When i execute, it displays correctly. But after i move to another activity and come back the image is not displaying. At that time my logcat shows,

```
W/System.err(3570): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
W/System.err(3570):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:116)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:274)
W/System.err(3570):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.read(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:40)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:166)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
W/System.err(3570):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
W/System.err(3570):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:573)
W/System.err(3570):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:628)
W/System.err(3570):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
W/System.err(3570):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Actually the error is showing in below line,

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

I've Searched and find different posts related to this in SO, but couldn't find any solution...
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

try this workaround by Jess from Google:

code to fix:

```
/**
 * This input stream won't read() after the underlying stream is exhausted.
 * http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562
 */
final class DoneHandlerInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private boolean done;

    public DoneHandlerInputStream(InputStream stream) {
        super(stream);
    }

    @Override public int read(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count) throws IOException {
        if (!done) {
            int result = super.read(bytes, offset, count);
            if (result != -1) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        done = true;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

To use, wrap the stream returned from getInputStream() in a DoneHandlerInputStream:

```
   InputStream stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
   stream = new DoneHandlerInputStream(stream);

   bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
   //rest of your code
```

see full explanation at:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14562

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
URL url = new URL(url);
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {  

try {

    Bitmap bm = null;

    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    return bitmap;

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmap.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            is.close();//add
        conn.disconnect();//add
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Might be accessing an http**s** endpoint with a **http** url